# Find reason for IIS "app crash" for .net MVC 5 application results in iis hanging

Tags: c#, .net, iis, azure-application-insights

My webapp (.NET MVC 5) randomly hangs and stops responding to requests. I can't seem to get any more details regarding this except for an "information entry" in the event log. It looks like this:

```
Fault bucket 120750848795, type 4
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0
Problem signature:
P1: w3wp.exe
P2: 10.0.14393.0
P3: 57899b8a
P4: MicrosoftInstrumentationEngine_x64.dll
P5: 0.1.22.16258
P6: 5820cd0f
P7: c00000fd
P8: 000000000004cd28
P9: 
P10:
```

Does thies mean that it is the "MicrosoftInstrumentationEngine_x64.dll" that is causing the crash? How can I get additional information regarding what is going on?

Comment: How are you hosting it?

Comment: I'm hosting it on premise on a windows server 2016 in IIS version 10.0.14393.0

Comment: Pls try to uninstall `Microsoft Monitoring Agent`, Then run for a period of time to check.

Comment: If it works, please let me know.

Comment: @JasonPan I did not have the possibility to make such a change at this stage. I turned on crashdumps for this specific error but It has not happened since.